# Animation for swipe action in SwiftUI List

Tags: swift, swiftui

have this simpel `NavigationView`

```swift
import SwiftUI
struct ExampleStruct: Identifiable, Equatable {
    static func == (lhs: ExampleStruct, rhs: ExampleStruct) -> Bool {
        lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
    
}

struct TestView: View {
    @State var items = [
        ExampleStruct(name: "An Item 0"),
        ExampleStruct(name: "An Item 1"),
        ExampleStruct(name: "An Item 2"),
        ExampleStruct(name: "An Item 3"),
    ]
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(items) { item in
                    NavigationLink {
                        Text("Hello there!")
                            .transition(.slide)
                    }label: {
                        Text(item.name)
                    }
                    .swipeActions(edge: .trailing, allowsFullSwipe: true) {
                        Button {
                            if let index = items.firstIndex(of: item) {
                                items.remove(at: index)
                            }
                        } label: {
                            Text("Delete")
                        }
                        .tint(.red)

                    }
                    .swipeActions(edge: .leading, allowsFullSwipe: true) {
                        Button {
                            withAnimation {
                                if let index = items.firstIndex(of: item) {
                                    items.remove(at: index)
                                }
                                items.insert(item, at: 0)
                            }
                            
                        } label: {
                            Image(systemName: "pin")
                        }
                        .tint(.orange)

                    }
                    
                }
            }
        }
       
    }
}

struct TestView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TestView()
    }
}
```

There is nothing wrong with the code and everything works. The only thing is the delete animation. The item just disappears instead of some nice animation as the `.onDelete` modifier gives me (I can not use onDelete because I want a leading swipe action).

Just wrapping the delete code in a with Animation works but produces a very bad looking animation.

How can I specify a custom transition for the deletion of an item?

Comment: You can specify the animation you want to use by using the `withAnimation(_:_:)` initializer.

Comment: Sadly this does not work. Say I nest my remove code in the `withAnimation(_:_:)` block with a duration of 10 seconds. Not even the duration is showing

Comment: I finally got back to this. Did you ever put `withAnimation` on your first `.swipeActions` that deletes things? When I do, it animates normally.

Comment: "Just wrapping the delete code in a with Animation works, but produces a very bad looking animation."

Comment: You posted coded did not include "wrapping the delete code in with Animation". You only wrapped the "Pin" swipe action. Regardless, that is the default delete animation, and it appears it cannot be changed

Comment: Okay. Yes you are right. I mentioned it in one sentence but I understand that you might misunderstood it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might want to change the role of the button to `.destructive`, so SwiftUI enables a delete animation automatically.

As [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/swipeactions(edge:allowsfullswipe:content:)) say:

> When you set a role for a button using one of the values from the ButtonRole enumeration, SwiftUI styles the button according to its role.

Setting the role to `.destructive` will make it red-tinted and have a delete animation when swiped by default.

Answer (score 0):

try changing

```
if let index = items.firstIndex(of: item) {
    items.remove(at: index)
}
items.insert(item, at: 0)
```

with

```
items.move(fromOffsets: index, toOffset: 0)
```

then your code will be

```
.swipeActions(edge: .leading, allowsFullSwipe: true) {
    Button {
        withAnimation {
            items.move(fromOffsets: index, toOffset: 0)
        }
        
    } label: {
        Image(systemName: "pin")
    }
    .tint(.orange)

}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**